# Sidebar que se vuelva fijo al tocar navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css3

Cómo están.
Estoy intentando hacer un sidebar (que también cumple el rol de formulario) que al comenzar el scrolling se quede fijo al chocarse con el navbar, que está fijo en la parte superior.
Me funciona, pero al momento de fijarse se produce un pequeño salto, no ocurre "naturalmente".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sidebar = $('#side');
  var nav = $('#navbar');
  var top = sidebar.offset().top - parseFloat(sidebar.css('margin-top'));
  var navBar = nav.offset().top - parseFloat(nav.css('height'));

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ((y >= top) && (y >= navBar)) {
      sidebar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cont {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 114px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cont,
.sidebar {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 custom_width">
  <div id="side" class="cont">
    <div style="background-color:#fff;height:250px;" class="sidebar">
      <h1 class="remove_margin">FORM</h1>
      <form id="crmform" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Name" class="form-control crm_item required crm_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control crm_item required crm_lastname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control crm_item required crm_email" /><span class="glyphicon, glyphicon-warning-sign, form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Phone" onKeyPress="phone_change()" onKeyUp="phone_change()" class="form-control crm_item required crm_phone" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Company" class="form-control crm_item required crm_company" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <a type="submit" class="btn form-control submit disabled crm_submit">Submit</a></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDICIÓN 1**
Sé que debo sumarle a este elemento `var y = $(this).scrollTop();` la altura del nav. Me está faltando eso, porque en este momento solo me detecta la altura de la pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar midiendo la altura del nav con `.outerHeight()`, y sumándoselo a `$(this).scrollTop()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $sidebar = $('#side');
    var $nav = $('#navbar');
    var top = $sidebar.offset().top - parseFloat($sidebar.css('margin-top'));

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
      var y = $(this).scrollTop() + $nav.outerHeight(true);

      if (y >= top) {
        $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
      } else {
        $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
      }
    });
});
```

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta colocando la propiedad `transition: all 0.5s` a `.fixed`

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 114px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.5s
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Comment: No funciona, ya lo había probado. Muchas gracias de todas formas!